# What is the meaning of "to have" in old cartoons?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, colloquialisms, semantic-shift, twentieth-century-english

In old cartoons, particularly "Little Red Riding Rabbit" of Looney Tunes, characters say "to have" with a meaning that seems different to the modern sense. For example, in the said cartoon, Little Red Riding Hood says that she is bringing a rabbit to her grandma "to have, see?".

What is the meaning of "to have" in that case?

That cartoon is not the only instance I've heard it but I can't recall any other exact cases. It just seems out of place in modern English and I'm convinced it's more than just the literal meaning of "having" or "to eat" in little red's case.

I don't mean this in an "I'm learning English" kind of way but in a "how was this used in colloquial spoken English in the ~40s" kind of way.

Comment: More context is need for “to have, see?” Can you link to a cartoon?

Comment: https://youtu.be/0TwubBMMAQQ?t=70

Comment: In that context I would interpret it to mean "to have to eat".

Comment: Although it might be intended to mean "to keep" (vs taking it home when I leave).

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think that what she's saying at 1:20 is "to have."

Comment: @alphabet - I've listened to it about 20 times, and it sounds like "to have" to me.  But I'd be glad to get some other opinions.

Comment: @alphabet — She is saying *to have*; read her lips to see the *v*.

Comment: And "to have" in that context either means "to eat" or "to possess".

Answer (score 7):

Based on this [“Little Red Riding Rabbit” TVTropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/LittleRedRidingRabbit), ***ta have*** is an affectation of Red:

> Verbal Tic: Red ends a lot of her lines with the exclamation “Ta’
> *Have!*”, just another thing that makes her so very *irritating*.

The [Likely Looney, Mostly Merrie blog](http://likelylooneymostlymerrie.blogspot.com/2017/07/420-little-red-riding-rabbit-1943.html) reports:

> Red is stereotyped as a loud, obnoxious bobby-soxer teenager -
> vocalised irritatingly by Bea Benaderet with great comedy values. . .
> . The character was the inspiration of radio comedian Cass Daley - and
> Michael Maltese’s young daughter! Daley was known for her energy and
> loudness; but some of Red’s childlike dialogue (“ta-have!”) was
> adapted from Maltese’s daughter.

This is backed up by the [TVTropes Trivia page for “Little Red Riding Rabbit”](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0037022/trivia):

> According to Mike Maltese’s daughter, Brenda, “I was that obnoxious
> girl [in the Bugs Bunny cartoon’ Little Red Riding Rabbit.’]” Brenda
> used to shout “Ta have!” as a girl and Mike put it in the story. When
> this cartoon was released in 1944, Brenda Maltese was not quite six
> years old, a little young for the part, so she was drawn as a teenage
> bobby-soxer, in a parody of comedienne Cass Daley.

You can see the full version of “Little Red Riding Rabbit” and all of Red’s *ta have*s at https://archive.org/details/looney-tunes-s-1944e-01-little-red-riding-rabbit.

So, unless you can find instances of ***ta have*** uttered by people other than Red (minus those inspired by her), *to have* means nothing beyond the usual sense of *to own* or *to possess*.

Comment: Excellent research, +1!

Comment: That's definitely great research but why would a bobby-soxer or another person say "ta have" like that? What does it mean that it is "childlike"? THIS is what I'm trying to understand.